# Why can I not close my JAR executable in this way?

Tags: java, c#, cmd, process, executable-jar

I have written a piece of software that requires me to open and close an executable jar file. 
At the moment I have the code able to open the jar with specific arguments 
(I have used notepad in the code example as I do not have the Jar file or my original code on me, and needed to test what I had written for this example worked) 
The issue I have is when I open and close notepad I get the correct behaviour, however when I try to close my JAR file I am not getting a response.

I have tried killing by the process name under task manager - go to details, the app name, and variants of java, java.exe, javaw etc.

Is it something to do with having launched the jar through CMD? 
in which case I have another issue because I have several processes with the exact same name and am not sure how to get the ID when the name is the same.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Click on the link below to continue learning how to build a desktop app using WinForms!
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://aka.ms/dotnet-get-started-desktop");

    }


    //string jarFile = "/JarLocation";
    //string jsonlocation = "/jsonlocation";
    //string command = $"java - jar {jarfile} -qsArgs {jsonLocation}";
    string command = "Notepad";
    string processName = "Notepad";
    List<int> processIDs = new List<int>();
    int[] processID;

    Thread testThread;
    ThreadStart ts;

    private void RunButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Running!");

        // METHOD 1     // Launch through CMD directly (in a new thread and try to terminate by process name)     
        /*
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            LaunchClient();
        }).Start();
        */


        // METHOD 2 // Generate 
        /*
        foreach (int ID in processIDs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Process {ID} Created");
        }
        */

        //Method 3
        /*
        testThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LaunchClient()));
        //testThread.Start();
        */

        // Method 4
        ts = delegate { LaunchClient(); };



    }

    private void KillButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Killing!");
        try
        {
            // Method 1

            Process[] ProcList = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
            foreach (Process targetProc in ProcList)
            {
                targetProc.CloseMainWindow();
            }



            // Method 2
            /*
            foreach (int ID in processIDs)
            {
                Process killMe = Process.GetProcessById(ID);
                killMe.CloseMainWindow();
            }
            */

            // Method 3
            //testThread.Abort();

            //Method 4
            //ts.EndInvoke();

        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("f.StackTrace");
        }
    }

    public void LaunchClient()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false;
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        //proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.Start();
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
        proc.StandardInput.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine($"PROCESS ID: {proc.Id}");
        processIDs.Add(proc.Id);
        //proc.StandardInput.Close();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }

}
```

Sorry to dump a large swathe of code but I thought seeing my implementation of the opening as well as the close would help.

EDIT:

Updated the code sample given to show the 4 different ways I have tried to handle this.

```
Method 1: 
Closing process by name (works for notepad, but not my jar)
2: Trying to pass the process ID back and use that to close the process 
(Cant see the ID outside of the thread running the cmd window)
3: using new threadstart (launchclient says 'method name expected')

4:  Doesn't open Notepad at all.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JAR file is opened with your code, an useful technique is to listen for windowClosing, which happens when the user clicks the X button on Windows (and the equivalent on other systems):

```
   addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          System.exit(0);
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the user will not be closing the window. All of this will be done by the software at certain times